# Nhibernate - Table-Valued Functions

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I can generate the following SQL:

> [dbo].[CategoryMatch]([CategoryId], ???) = 1

With the following HQL generator:

```
treeBuilder.Equality(treeBuilder.MethodCall("[dbo].[CategoryMatch]", new[] {
    visitor.Visit(arguments[0]).AsExpression(),
    visitor.Visit(arguments[1]).AsExpression()
}), treeBuilder.Constant(1));
```

However I've found this doesn't perform aswell as saying:

> [CategoryId] IN (SELECT [Id] FROM [dbo].GetCategories(???))

How could I adapt my HQL generator above with the new SQL? I'd appreciate the help. Thanks

**Update:**

So far I've come up with the following:

```
treeBuilder.In(
    visitor.Visit(arguments[0]).AsExpression(),
    treeBuilder.SelectFrom(
        treeBuilder.From(
            treeBuilder.Range(
                treeBuilder.MethodCall("[dbo].[GetCategories]", new[] {
                    visitor.Visit(arguments[1]).AsExpression()
                }).AsExpression(),
                treeBuilder.Alias("c")
            )
        )
    )
);
```

But this gives the error:

> Specified method is not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to come up with the following:

```
treeBuilder.In(
    visitor.Visit(arguments[0]).AsExpression(),
    treeBuilder.MethodCall("SELECT [Id] FROM [dbo].[GetCategories]", new[] {
        visitor.Visit(arguments[1]).AsExpression()
    }).AsExpression()
)
```

It's abit of a hack but it works so I guess it will do for now.